# React Navigation Issue with NavigationActions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an application in which I am trying to apply navigation in some case. For example, **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** are my *tabs* and in the **tab** **A**, I have `3` pages as `1`, `2`, `3`. Now in a situation where I am on **tab A** and on `page 3`, there is one button present in which I have to navigate back to `page 1` on the same tab itself **(A)**.
But somehow, my navigation is not working in this case. Below are my codes:

**SkippedTask.js**

```
 import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  AsyncStorage,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Alert
} from "react-native";
import ButtonC from "../../components/ButtonC";
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

import Server from "../../provider/Server";

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class SkippedTask extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadingState: false,
      api: new Server(),
      mobile: "",
      arrayLenght: "",
      tasklist: [],
      taskTitle: []
    };
  }

  renderSkippedQues() {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 0 }}>
        {this.state.taskTitle.map((item, key) => (
          <View key={key} style={{ marginTop: 0 }}>
            <Text style={{}}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: "#000" }}>{"\u2022"} </Text>{" "}
              {item}
            </Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }

  handleNav = () => {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "DashboardTab" })]
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.arrayLenght <= 0) {
      return <View />;
    } else {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginTop: height / 40
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "black", marginTop: 30 }}>
              List of skipped task are :
            </Text>
            {this.renderSkippedQues()}
            <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }} />
            <ButtonC
              title="    Click here to complete remaining task   "
              onPress={this.handleNav}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my **App.js** file in which I am using `StackNavigator` of `react-navigation`.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import SessionCheck from './src/screens/SessionCheck';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './src/screens/RegisterScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/ProfileScreen';
import WalletsScreen from './src/screens/WalletsScreen';
import DashboardAccept from './src/screens/DashboardAccept';
import TermsConditionsScreen from './src/screens/TermsConditionsScreen';
import DashboardTabScreen from './src/screens/DashboardTabScreen';
import Person from './src/components/profile/Person';
import Payment from './src/components/profile/Payment';
import List from './src/components/task/List';

const App = StackNavigator({

  // DashboardTab: { screen:DashboardTabScreen },
  Home: { screen: SessionCheck },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
  Profile: { screen:ProfileScreen },
  Wallets: { screen:WalletsScreen },
  DashboardAccept: { screen:DashboardAccept },
  TermsConditions: { screen:TermsConditionsScreen },
  DashboardTab: { screen:DashboardTabScreen },
  Person: {screen: Person},
  Payment : {screen: Payment},
  AllTask:{screen: List}
});

export default App;
```

Now my case lies that I need to navigate from the **SkippedTask** page to **AllTask** screen as mentioned in the **App.js** file. But somehow I am not able to resolve this issue.

*Any leads are appreciated. Thanks.*

Comment: If I am right, you have 3 pages in Tab A. So you may have added the 3 pages in another subtab inside Tab A. So when you try to move from page 3 to page 1. you can check the "initialRouteName" tag and set to Page 1.

Comment: I didn't get this one..... can you please explain in brief... Currently, I am using a function ( handleNav in above codes) in which I am setting the index to 0 and calling NavigationsActions..... This method is working absolutely fine in every other place..... but not in the case as mentioned above...... this is why I am little worried.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Also from your code, you're using `react-navigation` and not `react-native-navigation`

Comment: True.... my mistake..... I am not getting any error, doubled checked console too... When I am trying to click the button on the screen, nothing is happening. That's all

Comment: One more thing would be to log `this.props.navigation` in your `SkippedTask.js`, does it return a valid object?, since the route has not been defined in your `StackNavigator`.

Comment: the route has been defined in my StackNavigtor and it does not return any object, neither in the other tabs where its working perfectly........

Comment: @PritishVaidya can you have a small look at my code through team viewer.... cause still i am unable to resolve this.....